# No package sendmail available

Tags: php, sendmail

Unfortunately, my server is unable to send email.
I found the following tutorial by searching the web:

https://pepipost.com/tutorials/install-sendmail-server-centos-7/

But when I enter the `sudo yum install sendmail sendmail-cf m4` command, I get the following output

```
[root@server ~]# sudo yum install sendmail sendmail-cf m4
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.alpix.eu
 * updates: linux.darkpenguin.net
No package sendmail available.
No package sendmail-cf available.
Package m4-1.4.16-10.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

How ca I do add sendmail & sendmail-cf packages?

sorry i'm new in Linux

Thanks

**EDIT**
Step 1 in tutorial (`sudo yum install epel-release`) has this result:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile epel/x86_64/metalink | 31 kB 00:00 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net * extras: mirror.alpix.eu * updates: linux.darkpenguin.net base | 3.6 kB 00:00 extras | 2.9 kB 00:00 updates | 2.9 kB 00:00 Package epel-release-7-12.noarch already installed and latest version Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the epel-release repository run the command below

`sudo yum install epel-release`

Then try your yum install again and it should see the packages this time. If you aren't sure exactly what a package is called, you can also try

`sudo yum search (packageName)`   where the package name in this case would be sendmail

Comment: Thanks, but this is first step in tutorial, and result comes in my next comment

Comment: `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  31 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.alpix.eu
 * updates: linux.darkpenguin.net
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 2.9 kB     00:00
Package epel-release-7-12.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: If you run the yum search, do you see any packages listed that resemble Sendmail?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below commands:

```
#yum repolist
```

O/P

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * epel: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * extras: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * updates: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
repo id                                  repo name                                                              status
base/7/x86_64                            CentOS-7 - Base                                                        10,097
epel/x86_64                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                         13,217
extras/7/x86_64                          CentOS-7 - Extras                                                         338
updates/7/x86_64                         CentOS-7 - Updates                                                      1,787
repolist: 25,439
```

If you do not have epel enabled please try enabling it. By the way sendmail is coming from Centos-Base repository.

If you have epel enabled then you should be able to download the packages with below commands:

```
#yum install sendmail sendmail-cf m4
```

O/P

```
======================================================================================================================
 Package                      Arch                    Version                             Repository             Size
======================================================================================================================
Installing:
 m4                           x86_64                  1.4.16-10.el7                       base                  256 k
 sendmail                     x86_64                  8.14.7-5.el7                        base                  736 k
 sendmail-cf                  noarch                  8.14.7-5.el7                        base                  186 k
Installing for dependencies:
 cyrus-sasl                   x86_64                  2.1.26-23.el7                       base                   88 k
 procmail                     x86_64                  3.22-36.el7_4.1                     base                  171 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+2 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 1.4 M
Installed size: 3.5 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

Comment: Thanks santosh, my eple is enabled but I want to install the sendmail receive the same error `No package sendmail available.
No package sendmail-cf available.`

Comment: Can you paste `yum repolist` o/p.

Comment: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.alpix.eu
 * updates: linux.darkpenguin.net
repo id             repo name                                         status
base/7/x86_64       CentOS-7 - Base                                    9,958+139
epel/x86_64         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64    12,329+888
extras/7/x86_64     CentOS-7 - Extras                              338
updates/7/x86_64    CentOS-7 - Updates                       1,757+30
repolist: 24,382

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are adding new repo it's already available with your centos itself not all packages installed by default. Since your epel repo is 7-12 i guess you are using centos7.12. Here is all list of available packages what you have to do mount the cd and make local repo and use yum to install.

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/

Steps to create DVD/CD repo

1. create dir

   mkdir /cdrom                         '''make mount point for dvd/cd

   mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom              '''mount it on /cdrom dir
2. create new repo file

   vi /etc/yum.repos.d/local.repo
3. Add the following details

   [mediarepo]

   name=mediarepo

   baseurl=file:///cdrom

   enabled=1

   gpgcheck=1

   gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

We are ready now. Do cleanup.

```
yum clean all
```

And now you can use it.

```
yum search sendmail
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks asktyagi. It is true. My operating system is centos7. Please explain further how can I enable sndmail?

Comment: Added steps to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today, and the solution was to remove 'sendmail*' from the 'exclude' line in /etc/yum.conf. After that, installing sendmail worked.